# How can i clone this function that previews name necklaces with different fonts?

Tags: function

This website is for jewelry, and it allows users to write their name and they get a perfect preview of the necklace with different fonts and extra accessories attached.

http://create.ishajewelry.net/namenecklace

How can i clone it?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by cloning function?

Comment: @Nur I mean i want to clone the whole page with that function that allows you to preview the name so i can use it on my website!